# How to convert gson jsonarray to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, gson

I am getting huge json response from server, I am taking json array part from that json response and I am converting into json array using gson json array after that I need to put into json object, there I am getting out of memory exception.

log:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
 JsonArray customArray = gson.toJsonTree(list.getAsJsonArray();
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(customArray.toString());  // here  i am getting out of memory
 schoolListObject.put("list", jsonArray);
```

Comment: In manifest add `android:largeHeap="true"`
P.S. How large is the array you are getting?

Comment: That's a bad design to be honest. The API should not do that, it should only send the most important/relevant data first or add an ability for customizing offsets and limits.

Comment: What is the `list` in your code?

Comment: @Enzokie Despite you're completely right on how the data should be exposed, but some public services neglect this design approach. The OP can probably decrease the consumed memory in case of proper data transformation (say avoiding `toString()` in favor of `JSONTokener` or making a few requests slicing the response at a more low-level layer).

Comment: list means arraylist of countries list,this is a offline app so that first time we are retrieving whole response in one shot

Comment: @parker I meant how it's declared elsewhere, not the exact purpose.

Comment: @parker IMO it would be better to perform many request rather than one with a huge response. Furthermore, if the app works offline, maybe it would be worthwhile to zip the response and unzip it on the device.